# UIView suddenly disappears

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a native iOS app that creates a view hierarchy by pushing ViewControllers onto the root navigation controller.

Occasionally I find that the app suddenly disappears.  It doesn't appear to have crashed, because the App is still present within the iPad task bar.  But it seems that one or more of the views unloads, dropping the user back to the homepage.  The App is still visible in the iPad taskbar, and can be reopened by tapping on the icon in the taskbar.

Can UIViews just disappear like this?  How can I go about debugging this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Sounds like the app is crashing to me. Does Xcode report anything when running this?

Comment: Wouldn't a crashed app disappear from the task bar?

Comment: No. The app's icon remains in the multi-tasking bar after a crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS apps can't be hidden or minimized so if you are using your app and suddenly you are in the Home screen where all the apps are listed, then your app Crashed.

If you are using Xcode to install and test your application you can go to Organizer->devices and select your device and check the device log to see what happened when your app crashed.

This of course, if nothing is displayed on the console/Debug area when the app crashed.

If you aren't using ARC in your app and if nothing is been displayed on the Debug Area when the app crashes, then I'll bet is a Low Memory crash, those kind of crashes usually don't give time to Xcode to log the error but you can validate this on the Device log. If so, I'll recommend to switch and use ARC in your app.

Comment: But if it is crashing wouldn't you expect it to go missing from the task bar that you can open at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: No. The app's icon remains in the 'multi-tasking' bar after a crash.

Comment: @whatdoesitallmean No. It stais in the taskbar and if you select it it just restarts. Your app crashed.

Comment: No, Not all the apps in the task bar are opened, the task bar is more like a list of Recent Apps opened. Some of them are running on brackground and some of them not. The iOS closes the heavier apps when required, but the icons of those closed apps remains on the task bar.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that.  That answers the question then!   Thanks.

Comment: To complete the explanation: If you remove the app from the task bar then you make sure the app will be closed, but if the app is there it doesn't mean that is open.

Answer (score 1):

> It doesn't appear to have crashed, because the App is still present within the iPad task bar.

That really doesn't tell you anything. The "task bar" you describe isn't a list of processes that are currentlyl running; it's a list of apps that have been used recently. The listed apps may or may not be running right now.

To tell if your app crashed or not, select the device in the Xcode organizer, and look at the list of Device Logs. If your app crashed, the most recent log file will be listed with your app name under the Process column. Select that log and take a look -- you may see something like:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x80938733
Crashed Thread:  0
```

The rest of the log will give you some information about what each thread was doing at the time of the crash.

It also may happen that the most recent log(s) are not from your app, but instead listed under the Process and Type columns as `Unknown/Unknown`. The log will contain only a list of processes and the number of memory pages that each was using. Look for your app in the list, and you may find a line like:

```
MyApplication <23b...9af>   168389   168389  [per-process-limit] (frontmost) (resume)
```

If you see that, your app didn't crash; it was killed by the operating system because it was using too much memory. This is a good time to start using Instruments to profile your app's memory usage and look for very large allocations and/or memory leaks.